# How to Animate The Child while the parent is already animated

Tags: animation, objects, parent

Trying to animate the child relative to the parent animation , but the result always offset from the original placed position . Even though I Keyframed At The Same Position (By Using *ALT+G*) It Still Jump

Here's the problem + Blendfile :
[image]

I saw the only one solution that didn't work :
https://youtu.be/sUdV9qQXmVk

Also , this is not about parents and unparenting . The whole internet only gives me the "child of" constraint , which isn't what I mean ..!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s3bd.gif)

Update : deleting the config file WORKS ! Things is going well , the problem won't occur anymore .. what makes the problem is still unknown .. since I have 30+ add-ons installed .
Maybe some of my configuration is messed up , maybe some addon changes the behavior , maybe I shouldn't use Windows config to linux config .. who knows .

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: could you try it without auto keying? just insert your keyframes manually like you did with the cube.

Comment: @moonbots the problem is "practicable" , I mean you can create something similar and the problem will shows .

Comment: @bstnhnsl the result is same .

Comment: actually I can't replicate your problem so maybe it would be good to take a look at your file

Comment: @moonbots there , idk what you'll do about is since you wont see the problem right away , but i've try alt+G the child and add a keyframe there .. Still Jump

Comment: weird because in works fine on my computer, I can correct the animation just moving the pyramid above the cube and it will stay above, might be a bug on your Blender version? (my version goes back several months ago)

Comment: Sombody help close this question .

Answer (score 0):

In my case turning OFF [Preferences / Animation / Visual Keying] fixes the problem.